# Looking at brewing smoothie sours - is there a pasteurization process and are cans a must for them?

Tags: packaging

I am thinking about venturing into smoothie sours, but after doing a bit of reading it seems that keeping them shelf stable is a challenge. It also seems that canning is one of the only ways to actually produce them because of the thickness and nature of the fruit puree which may simply become impossible to rinse from a bottle.

I wanted to know what the key guidelines are on how to package and store smoothie sours considering there are a lot of fermentables still left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't recommend kegs enough. I resisted them for many batches, until I finally got a little 2.6gal one that fits in my fridge, and bought the hardware and co2 to charge it. Cleaning and packaging is incredibly convenient compared to bottling so unfermented slurry would no longer be a problem- provided you kept it away from the output tube.

Kegs also unlock other techniques, like purging oxygen out with CO2 before filling, so your brew preserves much better.

I hope that answers your question. For strictly can-vs-bottle, I can't think of any difference between them other than the fact that canning requires a lot of equipment and cans can't be reused. If a beer bottle doesn't hold enough pressure, just get one that does- champagne bottles are much stronger and hand corkers are cheap.

As for stopping fermentation, it's up to the brewer, but I expect one of 2 methods is used:

1. Just let the yeast ferment until they can't anymore, and package at that point, like a sweet mead or champagne.
2. Use a chemical additive like Campden tablets to kill off the yeast.